# Sample persistence.xml for a production instance using jpa2 and hibernate 3.6.x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

```
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
```

In a production scenario, it would make sense to switch the above flag to false. What other flags should be modified so that hibernate engine is optimized for a faster speed accessing a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

It depends :) you can set cache sizes, fetch depth (for outer joins), fetch batch sizes and many more things.

You probably don't want to log too much (show_sql => set to false, format_sql => set to false, use_sql_comments => set to false).

But really, it depends and you have to measure.

It is also important to use and properly configure a connection pool. 
Here again: Use common sense and measure.

Hopefully, these links will prove to be useful:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

The crucial point is to get the model right. Performance will be an issue if many sql requests are generated that do massive joins. So if performance is critical, you have to spend some thinking on normalization or in fact on NOT doing too much normalization in your entity-relationship modelling.

Also, collections and how you model/handle them can play a big role in terms of performance.

And as far as caching is concerned: Depending on your use case, you can improve performance by great lengths if you configure your second level cache (e.g. Ehcache) properly. That again means: Think about what can be cached and what not and how long-lived and how large your caches can and should be. So it really, reallly depends :)

Answer (score 0):

I Google'd for various combinations of useful keywords and I came up with a few useful links to point you in the right direction. Just remember, there will not be a SINGLE, DEFINITIVE list of "correct" properties for a production environment. People will recommend things based off of their experience but you will have to try things out and use common sense to figure out what works best for you.

[Hibernate Documentation of Available Configurable Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)

[Sample persistence.xml file for MySql](http://snipplr.com/view/4450/sample-persistencexml-that-uses-hibernate--mysql/)

The only property I have ever had to consciously remember to change for PROD configs is the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property which will allow Hibernate to directly alter your DB's schema by automatically executing DDL statements. For test DBs, it often makes sense to use a value of "create-drop" so that the test SessionFactory will create the necessary tables for you or change existing ones to match possible, recent schema changes. On prod, you DO NOT want to let Hibernate mess with your schema. Even the Hibernate guys warn to not use this feature in a production environment because data integrity is not guaranteed. The value you should use for prod is "validate" which will simply verify that the DB you are connecting to has the correct schema your Hibernate entities map to and it will fail to load the SessionFactory if there are discrepancies.